# Data is not inflating in android chat app

Tags: android

I am creating a chat process for a android app. Before I implement the chat on the original one I create a demo. On the demo my chat is working fine. But on the original app messages are sending successful but I am unable to get the messages from other side. I donot know why this is happening. I also compare the code but did not find any diff

Here is the code which work fine on demo but not on original app

```
public void Showchat() {

        SharedPreferences fids = getSharedPreferences("Friendidss", 1);
        String fid = fids.getString("friendid", "");
        final String ppid = fids.getString("propertyid", "");

        String logou = "http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/api/show_chatt_api.php?sender_id=";

        String url = logou + uid + "&receive_id=" + fid + "&property_id="
                + ppid;

        url = url.replace(" ", "+");

        Log.d("GetShowchatgeurllll", url);
        Log.d("GetShowchatgeurllll", url);
        Log.d("GetShowchatgeurllll", url);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url,
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("getprofileresponse", response.toString());

                        try {

                            String success = response.getString("success");

                            if (success.equals("1")) {

                                JSONArray userr = response.getJSONArray("user");
                                Integer size = userr.length();

                                listFrorecieveMsg.clear();
                                listFroSenderId.clear();
                                listForId.clear();
                                listFrorecieveId.clear();
                                listFroDate.clear();
                                listFroTime.clear();

                                Log.d("SIZEARRAY", size + "");
                                Log.d("sharedsize", pref.getMessageLength()
                                        + "");

                                for (int j = 0; j < userr.length(); j++) {

                                    JSONObject use = userr.getJSONObject(j);

                                    String cr_id = use.getString("cr_id");
                                    String date = use.getString("date");
                                    String time = use.getString("time");

                                    String sender_id = use
                                            .getString("user_id_fk");
                                    String receive_id = use
                                            .getString("user_id_rec");

                                    String message = use.getString("reply");

                                    int idd = Integer.parseInt(cr_id);

                                    listFrorecieveMsg.add(message);
                                    listFroSenderId.add(sender_id);
                                    listFroDate.add(date);
                                    listFrorecieveId.add(receive_id);
                                    listForId.add(idd);
                                    listFroTime.add(time);

                                    Log.d("mydatalogin", cr_id + " ," + message
                                            + ", " + sender_id);
                                    Log.d("mydatalogin", cr_id + " ," + message
                                            + ", " + sender_id);
                                    Log.d("mydatalogin", cr_id + " ," + message
                                            + ", " + sender_id);

                                }

                                if (first.equals("1")) {

                                    first = "2";

                                    if (uunnrreeaadd.equals("0")) {

                                        Showchat();

                                    } else {

                                        int messg = Integer
                                                .parseInt(uunnrreeaadd);

                                        int sss = size - messg;

                                        Log.d("Unreadmessage", "Size = " + size
                                                + " , " + "Position " + sss
                                                + " , UnredMessage =" + messg);

                                        for (int i = 0; i <= messg - 1; i++) {

                                            Log.d("Unreadmessage", "Size = "
                                                    + size + " , "
                                                    + "Position " + sss);

                                            String db_recvid = "", db_time = "", db_message = "", db_sender_id = "", db_date = "", db_Sender_name = "", db_reciver_name = "";
                                            Integer db_id;

                                            db_date = listFroDate.get(sss);
                                            db_id = listForId.get(sss);
                                            db_message = listFrorecieveMsg
                                                    .get(sss);
                                            db_recvid = listFrorecieveId
                                                    .get(sss);
                                            db_sender_id = listFroSenderId
                                                    .get(sss);
                                            db_time = listFroTime.get(sss);

                                            Log.e("size: ",
                                                    "size= "
                                                            + size
                                                            + " stored size: "
                                                            + pref.getMessageLength());
                                            db.open();

                                            Log.d("Insertdata", db_id + " "
                                                    + db_message + " "
                                                    + db_date + " " + db_time);
                                            Log.d("Insertdata", db_id + " "
                                                    + db_message + " "
                                                    + db_date + " " + db_time);
                                            Log.d("Insertdata", db_id + " "
                                                    + db_message + " "
                                                    + db_date + " " + db_time);

                                            db.insert(db_id, db_sender_id,
                                                    db_recvid, db_message,
                                                    db_date, ppid, db_time);

                                            Log.e("date ", "" + db_date);
                                            Log.e("message ", "" + db_message);
                                            Log.e("sender ", "" + db_sender_id);
                                            Log.e("id ", "" + db_id);
                                            Log.e("recv id ", "" + db_recvid);
                                            db.close();

                                            sss = sss + 1;

                                            getMessagesFromSqlite();
                                            // pref.setMessageLenght(sss);

                                        }

                                    }

                                } else {

                                    Log.d("Secondelse", "Secondelse");

                                    if (listFroSenderId.size() != 0) {

                                        String db_recvid = "", db_time = "", db_message = "", db_sender_id = "", db_date = "", db_Sender_name = "", db_reciver_name = "";
                                        Integer db_id;

                                        db_date = listFroDate.get(listForId
                                                .size() - 1);
                                        db_id = listForId.get(listForId.size() - 1);
                                        db_message = listFrorecieveMsg
                                                .get(listForId.size() - 1);
                                        db_recvid = listFrorecieveId
                                                .get(listForId.size() - 1);
                                        db_sender_id = listFroSenderId
                                                .get(listForId.size() - 1);
                                        db_time = listFroTime.get(listForId
                                                .size() - 1);

                                        if (size != pref.getMessageLength()) {
                                            Log.e("size: ",
                                                    "size= "
                                                            + size
                                                            + " stored size: "
                                                            + pref.getMessageLength());
                                            db.open();

                                            pref.setMessageLenght(size);

                                            Log.d("Insertdata", db_id + " "
                                                    + db_message + " "
                                                    + db_date + " " + db_time);

                                            db.insert(db_id, db_sender_id,
                                                    db_recvid, db_message,
                                                    db_date, ppid, db_time);

                                            Log.e("date ", "" + db_date);
                                            Log.e("message ", "" + db_message);
                                            Log.e("sender ", "" + db_sender_id);
                                            Log.e("id ", "" + db_id);
                                            Log.e("recv id ", "" + db_recvid);
                                            db.close();

                                            getMessagesFromSqlite();

                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        Showchat();
                                        listForShowChat
                                                .deferNotifyDataSetChanged();

                                    }
                                }).start();

                            } else {

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d("getprofileErrorresponse", "Error: "
                                + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // hide the progress dialog

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

    }
```

Comment: A little tip, that might help you in the long term. A nice library which you can use for communication with rest api's is [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) it might help you clean up the code a bit.